# PHP Netbeans Anonymous Functions

Tags: php, netbeans

Does anyone know how I can get **Anonymous Functions** to appear in the **Netbeans Navigator**? Is there a custom thing I can add like a comment block? (This is for PHP)
It becomes very difficult to navigate with many of these:

```
prggmr\handle(function() {
  foreach ($result as $user) {        
      prggmr\signal(Events::NOTIFICATION_ADD, $type, $content);
  }     
}, new Admin(Events::ADMIN_SYSTEM_NOTIFICATION_ADD));
```

Comment: Offtopic: I always wanted to thank you for your awesome programming videos, but I don't have a YouTube account... :) So, thanks for your effort and for sharing your knowledge, you gave me some really good ideas and helped me a lot with them!

Comment: Haha somebody found me on here! Well I am glad they helped you man :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you can add this to PHP classes for properties and methods, using PHPDocumentor (it's installed by default I think) like so:

```
/**
 * @method void my_method() my_method(string $var) This function does something
 * @property string $my_property
 */

class MyClass
{
    ....
```

Perhaps if you wrap your Anonymous (ironic?) Functions inside a class (if it's not already) you can do this.